# Find starting and end point of 1 in a list having 0s and 1s

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list and I want to find the starting and ending index of value 1.
Here is the list

```
labels=[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
```

The 1s index are `[3,5]` and `[8,9]`

Is there any efficient way to do this. I have tried numpy index(), but it did not work for me. Using it, either i can find first or last 1, but not the ones in middle.
This is what I have tried.

```
[labels.index(1),len(labels)-labels[::-1].index(1)-1]
```

This gives me `[3,9]` but i want to have indexes of consecutive 1s which is  `[3,5]` and `[8,9]`

Comment: In this case would the starting and ending index of value 1 be [3,9]?

Comment: Hi, i want to have it in such as way to find first and last index of consecutive ones

Answer (score 3):

One option, get the start of each stretch using `diff` and comparison to 0 after padding to ensure that the labels start and end with 0:

```
labels = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]

out = np.where(np.diff(np.pad(labels, 1))!=0)[0].reshape(-1,2)-[0,1]
```

output:

```
array([[3, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```

As list:

```
out.tolist()
# [[3, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by @mozway may be better suited to large lists. However, for such a small data set, this method is considerably faster (if that's important):

```
labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

def func(labels):
    result = []
    se = -1
    for i, e in enumerate(labels):
        if e == 1:
            if se < 0:
                se = i
        else:
            if se >= 0:
                result.append([se, i-1])
                se = -1
    if se >= 0:
        result.append([se, len(labels)-1])
    return result

print(func(labels))
```

**Output:**

```
[[3, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it by using itertools [compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). "Get indices of 1, group by consecutive indices and find first and last indice in group".

```
from itertools import groupby, compress, count

serie = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]      

stream = compress(*zip(*enumerate(serie)))    # indices of 1

consecutives = ([*streak] for _, streak in groupby(stream, lambda n,  c=count(): n - next(c)))  # streaks of consecutive numbers

indices = [[el[0], el[-1]] for el in consecutives]

-> [[3, 5], [8, 9], [11, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**For numpy and python beginners:**

```
labels=[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
indices=np.array(np.nonzero(labels))[0]
count,result = 0 , []
for idx in range(len(indices)-1):
    if indices[idx]+1==indices[idx+1]:
        count+=1
        if idx==len(indices)-2:
            result.append([indices[idx],indices[idx]+1])
    else:
        result.append([indices[idx]-count,indices[idx]])
        count=0
if indices[-1]-indices[-2]>1:
    result.append([indices[-1],indices[-1]])
print(result)

Output : [[3, 5], [8, 9], [11, 11]]
```